# BSON document to FilterDefinition<Bson> MongoDb c# driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

How can i convert a `BsonDocument` to the `FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>` instance?

It is a class provided by new MongoDb C# driver.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's an implicit cast between `BsonDocument` and `FilterDefinition`. You don't need to convert it:

```
BsonDocument bsonDocument = new BsonDocument();
FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> filterDefinition = bsonDocument;
```

Comment: As i noticed, you can use  any generic type in FilterDefinition, not only BsonDocument: the implicit cast works anyway!